# STM32 USB programming using the OTG interface

Tags: stm32, embedded, programming, stm32f4

I'm new to ARM based STM32 controller. The Controller which I'm using STM32F427VIT6. It has USB OTG FS interface where I need to program it using the USB interface. Is it possible to program or I have to use UART interface to program the controller.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microcontrollers are, by default, programmed using their so-called programming/debug interfaces. In case of STM32, it has SWD and JTAG interfaces for programming and debugging. You can use for example an ST-Link debugger to connect to these interfaces and program the device. If your application requires programming over USB or UART, you can use a [bootloader](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/b9/9b/16/3a/12/1e/40/0c/CD00167594.pdf/files/CD00167594.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00167594.pdf) to flash the microcontroller over these interfaces.

Comment: Yes, that is another option to program through serial. But can I use the USB programming(as it has DP, DM pins), which is given for the USB OTG interface

Comment: Yes, it is possible to access the bootloader using the DP/DM pins at PA11 and PA12. Check section 33 in the link I provided for more information.

Comment: But the pins for DP and DM are PB14 and PB15 respectively

Comment: Both PA11/12 and PB14/15 can be used for USB pins. However, the bootloader is configured to use the PA11/12. It won't work with PB14/15.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to try this case in CubeMx ?